# In which scripture does the Sun named Gabhasti appear

Tags: gods, hanuman

In the Hanumatsahasranaama from Rudrayaamala one of the name is Gabhastigraasako.
A few years ago I came across a stanza in sanskrit which roughly translated meant " ...At that time, in the constellation of Libra, a Sun named Gabhasti was giving birth to itself..."
Anyone know the source?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gabhasti or Gabhastika is mentioned as a form of the sun in chapter fifty-one of the Agni Purana:

> (4). (The images of) Agni and other gods bearing the club, trident, disc and lotus should be placed in different directions (around). (The images of) **the forms of Sun**, commencing with Aryamā are represented as possessing four arms and placed in a diagram of twelve petals.
>
> (5-6). Varuṇa, Sūrya, Sahasrāṃśu (one who has thousand rays), Dhātṛ, Tapana, Sāvitṛ, **Gabhastika**, Ravi, Parjanya, Tvaṣṭṛ, Mitra (and) Viṣṇu are his different names as he moves over the zodiacal signs commencing with the Aries in the course of months commencing with Mārgaśīrṣa and ending with Kārttika.
>
> (7-9). Their female energies known by the names—Iḍā, Suṣumnā, Viśvārcis, Indu, Pramardinī, Praharṣaṇī, **Mahākālī**, Kapilā, Prabodhanī, Nīlambarā, Ghanāntasthā and Amṛtā, and placed at the ends of petals are of black, red, pale red, yellow, pale yellow, white, **brown**, yellow, green, white, grey and blue.
>
> [(source)](https://archive.org/details/AgniPuranaUnabridgedEnglishMotilal/page/n141)

According to the [Puranic Encyclopaedia](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc241575.html), this specific form does indeed correspond to Libra.

On a side-note, Gabhastika is mentioned in the Skanda Purana as the tirtha (sacred place) associated with Sūrya: the 63rd of the 68 names of the sun. [(source)](https://archive.org/details/StudiesInSkandaPuranaPart2ABLAwasthi1978/page/n103)